# PulseIN not recognised

Tags: pulsein

I have included the library for the HCSR04 echo sounder, but `pulseIN` is not recognised; it never goes orange either.

I have tried multiple libraries, and closing down the IDE and opening it back up.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `pulseIN()` in the Arduino core. The function you are looking for is named `pulseIn()`. It's in the core library: you do not need to load anything extra. Beware that the language is case-sensitive.

Comment: What a simple mistake to make thankyou for giving me the answer.